# Is there an easy way to pause/resume some Sublime package?

Tags: sublimetext

Is there an easy way to pause some Sublime package without uninstall/install it.?

Sometimes I don't like to see some linter tools running, or I would like to check why my Sublime editor sometimes works slow when editing text, probable because of some package.

Also anyone downwoting this question. Please let me know the comment why.
I would applicate.

I strongly believe, when you have 20 packages and you need to pause 10 packages, to check something, it is handy to have a mean to do that just on a single click per package.

I would like to make my life easier.

Comment: Add the package's name to `"ignored_packages"` in your user settings.

Comment: I heard that, but I don't consider editing an easy way. I would like to click or smt.

Comment: I use 20 packages, why do I need to know the exact name of any and to typo. What if I would like to pause, 10 packages?

Answer (score 1):

Open the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> on Windows/Linux, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> on OS X) and start typing ***`Package Control: Disable Package`*** or a fuzzy shortcut, like ***`paccondi`*** until it's selected. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then either scroll down the list, or start typing the package's name. Once it's selected, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again, and it will be added to the `"ignored_packages"` list in your user preferences. Use ***`Package Control: Enable Package`*** to make it active again. Unfortunately, you can only do this for one package at a time.

You can find the list of installed packages in **`Preferences -> Package Settings -> Package Control -> Settings-User`** if you'd like to add several packages to `"ignored_packages"` at once.

Comment: OK, it is a good one-by-one approach for those who like old basketball rules.

Comment: @prosti this is pretty much the only way to do it. Sublime settings are controlled by JSON files, not by GUIs where you can select from a list of installed packages and move them *en masse* to the ignored list. You could theoretically write a plugin where you enter each package name in a popup to be added to `"ignored_packages"`, but it would be just as easy to add them directly.

Comment: there is always the right time to write the first ST plugin, I would consider that based on your feedaback, for some weekend. However, I can still hope there is a package out there but maybe hidden from our eyes.